# Sending Output of Script By mail

Tags: linux, cron, sendmail

I have a script to Monitor servers in Production , and I want to receive the result of this script execution every 2 hours by mail , how can I do this ? someone has an example ? this is my Script:

```
    #!/bin/sh
CheckPorts=`cd /DATA/scripts && sh checkPorts.sh`

CPU=`iostat -ch`

FreeMemory=`free -mh`

DISK_Space_DATA=`df -h /DATA`

DISK_Space_ROOT=`df -h /root`

Kafka=`ps -aux | grep kafka`

Spark=`ps -aux | grep spark`
# -CheckPorts:
echo -e "\e[31;43m***** Firewall Authorization *****\e[0m"

echo "${CheckPorts}"

echo ""
# -CPU:
echo -e "\e[31;43m***** CPU INFORMATION *****\e[0m"

echo "${CPU}"

echo ""
# -Free and used memory in the system:
echo -e "\e[31;43m ***** FREE AND USED MEMORY *****\e[0m"

echo "${FreeMemory}"

echo ""
# -File system disk space usage:
echo -e "\e[31;43m***** FILE SYSTEM /DATA DISK SPACE USAGE *****\e[0m"

echo "${DISK_Space_DATA}"

echo ""
# -File system disk space usage:
echo -e "\e[31;43m***** FILE SYSTEM /root DISK SPACE USAGE *****\e[0m"

echo "${DISK_Space_ROOT}"

echo ""
# -Spark Process Status:
echo -e "\e[31;43m***** Spark Process Status *****\e[0m"

echo "${Spark}"

echo ""
# -Kafka PROCESSES Status:
echo -e "\e[31;43m***** Kafka Processes Status *****\e[0m"

echo "${Kafka}"

echo ""

echo "Done"
```

Comment: If local mail delivery is set up on the machine, the output of cron jobs are mailed to the owner of the job. The mail is sent to the owner, or to the address specified in `$MAILTO` in the crontab. See `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: I did'nt get your point , I'm new in Linux so what you said is not clear for me

Comment: Have you already set up a cron job to run this script every two hours? It is not clear from the question whether the primary issue is getting the output mailed, or having the script execute every two hours (which would actually mail the output automatically).

Comment: I did a cron job , but in the log cron.log I don't find the result , there is just the path and permission denied , what does it means ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your script is called `monitor.sh`. There are many commands you can use on linux to send the email.

For example with `mail` command:

`mail -s "Monitor Report" admin@example.com < <( bash monitor.sh )`

With `sendmail`:

`echo "Subject: Monitor Report" | sendmail -v admin@example.com  < <( bash monitor.sh )`

With `ssmtp`:

`ssmtp admin@example.com < <( echo "Subject: Monitor" ; bash monitor.sh )`

With `curl` and gmail:

```
bash monitor.sh > report.txt
curl --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' --ssl-reqd \
  --mail-from 'developer@gmail.com' --mail-rcpt 'admin@example.com' \
  --upload-file report.txt --user 'developer@gmail.com:your-accout-password'
```

If you want this automatically every 2 hours, put the command on cron (see man crontab).

Chances are, your server already has one of the commands above properly configured to send email (`sendmail`, `mail`, `ssmtp`), if not, take a look how to install and configure those.

---

References:

https://blog.edmdesigner.com/send-email-from-linux-command-line/

https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/

Comment: I have used the method with sendmail and I get /usr/sbin/sendmail: No such file or directory
seems it needs something to be installed but  I don't want to install something in the server because it's a big procedure to do it

Comment: @AbdelAzizESSAADI Well, you need a program installed to send the email, there is no magic around that, see if your server has either `mail`, `mailx`, `ssmtp`, `curl`, `wget`, `telnet`.. Check the first link I pasted, it shows how to run many of these commands. If your server doesn't have any of those, you will need to have one of those installed.

Comment: okey thank you so much

Comment: the server as mail but it's not working when I put the command !! I don't receive anything `*/2 * * * * /DATA/scripts/Daily_Script.sh &> /DATA/scripts/cron.log && mail -s "APP2_Monitoring_Log" mail@example.ma </DATA/scripts/cron.log`

Comment: Any other help ??

Comment: @AbdelAzizESSAADI try to isolate the parts, see if just the mail command on the shell is working. if it is not, you may have to configure the mail command on the server. if it is working, try creating another script that calls the daily script and send the mail, check if this script runs fine when you call it manually, if it does, you put only this script on cron, instead of doing the redirects and pipes on the cron itself (which may not be supported by your cron implementation or work differently, e.g require different scapeing, etc)

Comment: when I run this command  `echo "This is a Test" | mail -s "sujet" `example@domain.ma  , the command don't show any error in command line , but don't receive anything !! I have installe sendmail by `yum install sendmail`

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you to get the expected result

```
echo "Hourly report : \n $(cat \$file.log)" | mailx -s "Subject : add_your_subject" example@gmail.com
```

You can even add `-a` to above mailx command to attach the log generated as an attachment

make sure if you want to add attachment .. generate the log with `date+time`   like below

```
ABC_12_09_2020_1_56_34.log
```

you can write some script that will pick latest file as an when the new log is generated and your mailx command while running should pick the latest log as an attachment